# How to import min3D in Android Studio?

Tags: android, min3d

I have tried Import into Subversion but it showing error.

> Cannot import to svn: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you have subversion installed on your system?

Comment: No. I am just following a tutorial. But they are using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://ubuntuanakramli.blogspot.in/2015/10/tutorial-on-min3d-framework-using.html) tutorials. This would help. I believe you were following [this](http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/) earlier.

Basically, create a golder named **min3d**, under the folder named Java from your project structure, and copy the source you had downloaded into the created mind3d folder.

Then right click - > add as reference/library. This should fix it.

Comment: Can you remove the negate in answer, as this is the right one? @PetterFriberg?

Comment: I did not vote on your answer, I never downvote or upvote, I only comment to help out OP and improve content on SO

Comment: @AgustinScalisi the first link is the answer and it works. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot run program "svn" <- this looks like you have to install SVN
you can optain it from: http://tortoisesvn.net/

Or verify that you are able to open SVN from command-shell:
Open a shell and type: `svn --help`

In case you get an error stating, that svn could not be found, you have to
set your path environment var.

> The PATH is the system variable that your operating system uses to
>   locate needed executables from the command line or Terminal window.
>
> (SVN) Subversion is a source version control system (VCS). Subversion
>   manages files and directories, and the changes made to them, over
>   time. This allows you to mange and recover diffent stages of your
>   development process.